# Best Practices: How do you protect your users from external urls?

Tags: security, url

We're implementing a website which is aimed to store links to open datasets uploaded by users.

This website is aimed to allow different companies to share datasets of information with other users, building a knowledgebase.

However, the requisite to store just the url to the dataset opens a dangerous security risk, as the content on the final url can change after any moderation process we enforce on our side of the operation.

So anyone can upload a legit url pointing to a legit page containing a dataset and, after I review and publish it on the website, they can redirect the url to a malicious site or content.

We have stated this as a problem to our customer, but they want us to look for a solution. Also... publishing external urls is an use case quite spreaded nowadays, and I supose it should be some best practices about how to enforce this task.

The first obvious option is to show a message before redirecting, warning the user about the obvious fact that he's leaving our site, but it seems quite whimsical for me.

We have thought about storing an md5 of the content on the moment of moderation, and checking against it when anyone is following the url, to ensure that the content hasn't changed. However, the main objective of the site is to store evolving datasets, which are intended to change, maybe even on an hourly basis, so this isn't also a good approach.

My question is: Anyone know about any best practices about how to implement safe external url redirections? How do you confront such functionalities from a security point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no single bullet-proof solution to your problem. But still it is possible to mitigate the risks by applying at least the following changes (if applicable to your application):

- User must register before being able to load/define a dataset URL. The registration process has to be secure, strict and robust enough to push back most malicious guys. Ask for email, verification of email, captcha, eventual personal or company information. Then enable Two-Factor authentication with phone number or anything similar that will even more "characterize" or "personalize" the user.
- Once the registration is secure and trusted then you will fear less about malicious changes to URLs.
- Manually verify each updated dataset (URL and site). Even better to automatize but quite hard. There are sandboxing tools for web sites. The tool could connect to the URL and perform security checks. I let you Google that.
- Use free or paid online site security checker. Each time an URL is updated, perform a security scan on this URL using tools like https://www.virustotal.com/ or https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/. I also let you Google about that.
- Eventually enforce high security standards for companies publishing their datasets. For instance request ISO27001 compliance. Not the most friendly solution but this is a guarantee of quality.
- Also request TLS-secured URLs and be sure certificates are valid when the URL is set (can be easily tested programmatically). You may also raise alerts or trigger manual verifications only when the domain changes in that case.
- Offer all users the possibility to signal a broken or malicious link

I will edit my post if something else comes into mind.. but I think the above propositions could already raise significantly the security level of your website. Of course don't forget to implement your own security by doing regular security assessment and penetration testing for example, and think security by design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some of your proposals were already on our roadmap, and maybe some of them are more aggresive on the user end than we'd like to. But I suppose that our client have to decide between security and user-friendliness.

Comment: This is indeed the battle of this century :) The very concept of user-friendliness will be crushed by security, no exception.